# Gibbs free energy the 3 equation confusion

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Hello can you please help me with thermochemistry? I have been taking chem classes since highschool and they ALL talked about Gibbs free energy, enthalpy, and entropy... even in college I got away with just aimlessly plugging and chugging into the 3 equations.

ΔG=ΔGo+RTln(Q/Keq)

ΔGo=-RTln(Keq)

ΔG=ΔH-ΔST

First I don't understand what gibbs free energy is, Kaplan book along with many other sources interchange between "energy released" and "total energy of the compound".... I think I need to be treated like a 5 year old because I want to once and for all understand what this is. What is gibbs free energy and how can I picture it if I were to picture a reaction. How do you explain this in terms of kinetic and potential energy. Okay I tried my best to understand it and I thought I got far, its the energy to drive the reaction forward... okay makes sense... ΔG is 0 at Keq.... GREAT universe makes sense, at Keq the reaction is at equilibrium so there is no more driving force left (I assume that IS gibbs free energy). BUT THAN there was an introduction of STANDARD gibbs free energy..... thats when I realized that I was wrong the whole time.... because at Keq standard gibbs free energy is NOT 0???? how come???

In the equation ΔG=ΔH-ΔST the S=Q/T but if the pressure is constant than Q=H (heat in /out= enthalpy- which is just the heat energy??????) so S=H/T and if temperature is constant than you can plug ST=T(H/T) and Temperatures cancel out (why do they cancel out? more specifically IF they cancel out than should they not cancel out EVERYTIME? and G=H-H which equals 0. So IF pressure is constant than Qrev=H always and water is being heated it up constant pressure than T(H/T) should the T's not cancel out anyways???? meaning water that is being heated has G=0.

Okay so I am obviously confusing WHEN to cancel temperature out because frankly I dont see how constant temperature cancels out because the equation ΔG=ΔH-ΔST does not seem to have a delta next to the T AND if it did than would make deltaT=0 which would make ST=0 which would mean delta G=H.

Okay BUT lets just IGNORE ALL THAT and LET ME memorize the fact that AT Keq deltaG is infact 0!  Okay but than ΔG=ΔGo+RTln(Q/Keq)

ΔGo=-RTln(Keq) these 2 equations RUINED that.... how can deltaG at Keq be 0 when it clearly is NOT! I know that standard G is the gibbs free energy (keep in mind I still dont know what this mysterious energy is) is calculated from standard states.... and even that is confusing to me... I thought standard state was 1atm, 1M, 298K and the standard gibbs free energy of formation used the SIMPLEST elements at their standard state (H2 gas+1/2O2gas->H2O liquid). But I must be wrong, I must be missing SOMETHING.... I am assuming my confusion of why standard G in NOT 0 at Keq is coming from misunderstanding the WHOLE concept all together.  ALSO ΔG=ΔGo+RTln(Q/Keq) equation besically states that equation at Keq has deltaG as well... the same delta G that I just blindly memorized to be 0 at Keq... what is going on here??????????

Comment: Think of a system that can exchange thermal energy only at a *fixed temperature* of the environment and exchange mechanical work only at a *fixed pressure*. If all the *other* processes the system is involved in such as chemical, electrical, magnetic, etc., are also reversible then the total sum of all that other work is potential, ie. independent of the process path and is equal to the change of the Gibbs potential (energy).

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of the "Van't Hoff equilibrium box?"

Comment: I am not familiar with that, Let me look it up.

Comment: The Van't Hoff equilibrium box concept is very useful in understanding the standard change in free energy, and the change in free energy under other non-equilibrium initial and final reaction mixtures.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics?

Comment: No, I am only familiar with state vs path functions. I am slowly chipping away at the equation though. I had a hard time understanding the vant hoffs equation. Right now I am watching Khan academy.

Comment: I didn't say van't Hoff's *equation*; I said van't Hoff's **equilibrium box.**  And you are saying that, in all your thermodynamics courses, you were never taught about the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics.  Were you taught about the closed system version of the first law $\Delta U=Q-W$?